# Does std::map require the comparator's operator() to be const?

Tags: c++, libc++

The following code fails to compile with XCode 4.5's clang++ when using libc++ on OS X 10.8:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
  explicit Foo(int val_) : val(val_) {}
  int val;
};

struct FooComparator {
  bool operator()(const Foo& left, const Foo& right) {
    return left.val < right.val;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::map<Foo, std::string, FooComparator> m;

  Foo f(4);
  m[f] = std::string("four");

  return 0;
}
```

The error:

> broken.cpp:11:8: note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument
>   has type 'const FooComparator', but
>         method is not marked const   bool operator()(const Foo& left, const Foo& right) {

If I turn off libc++ and build with libstdc++ then all is well. Obviously, I can work around this by making FooComparator::operator() const, but I'd like to understand whether this is a problem with libc++ being too strict, or whether the standard (both C++03 and C++11) does in fact require that the comparator's operator() be const (in which case the fact that it works with libstdc++ is a happy accident).

Comment: I've always wondered this too actually

Comment: Note: It is not possible to resolve this problem solely based on the fact that the `map` constructor accepts `const Compare &`; because Table 102 specifies that the `map` takes a copy of the comparator object.  (This point was originally made by Kerrek SB on an answer that is now deleted).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, yes: The comparator is a subobject of the map itself, one way or another (maybe a member; usually a base class of some inner implementation class). If you have a constant reference to the map, the comparator still needs to be usable for lookup, so the operator needs to be `const`.

Comment: I agree with the argument you are making, but I'm curious about how the standards (03, 11) state this. libstdc++ seems happy to instantiate a map with a comparator with a non-const operator() as long as you don't invoke that comparator in a constness violating fashion, while libc++ is not so permissive. Does the requirement that the comparator be const depend on the usage of the map? How do the standards state this, etc.

Comment: @acm: I don't think it's explicitly stated, but it's basically a consequence of all the other associative container requirements.

Comment: I know I'm nitpicking, because clearly the practical answer is "just make it const already". However, it seems to me that either it is legal to instantiate std::map with a comparator with non-const operator() as long as you don't use the map in such a way as to require constness (in which case libc++ seems to have an error where it requires comparator constness in a non-const context), or it isn't legal, and libstdc++ should reject the code above, but doesn't. Or does this somehow fall within implementation defined behavior, and so both are correct?

Comment: @acm: I couldn't find any specific statement to that effect, nor for *any* of the predicates used elsewhere in the standard. I think the requirement simply follows implicitly from the other container requirements, and it is left unspecified how much an implementation cal allow you to get away with a non-const operator.

Comment: How could the requirement logically follow from the spec when a straightforward implementation of the spec does not require it?

Comment: @Nemo: The standard specifies the signatures of various accessor functions, and those functions in turn are specified to use the comparator. The comparator is required to be owned by the container. So if the accessor function is const, then the comparator must support that. Thus the comparator's operator must be const for those use cases, and thus always. If the implementation allows using certain non-const accessors with a non-const operator, then that's not a contradiction.

Comment: @Kerrek:  Not sure I buy this logic.  The signatures for C++03 `vector<T>` (for example) imply that `T` is copy constructible, yet the standard's authors felt the need to say so explicitly.  Why would they not be equally explicit here?  I would call this ambiguous at best...

Comment: @Nemo: that's a different issue. `auto_ptr` is formally copy-constructible, but it doesn't have the right *semantics*. So the standard specifies what it means for an object to be copyable (i.e. the copy is the same as the original) and mandates that your element type be such (at the pain of undefined behaviour). The equivalent requirement for the comparison object also exists: the standard requires that repeated calls always give the same result.

Comment: The standards committee resolved this as http://wg21.link/LWG2542. The comparator's operator () is required to be const. Note that this is a defect report against the earlier standards; not a new feature for C++17 (though C++17 will be the first standard with this wording)