# std::map non-const functors, compile time error under clang++, ok for g++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, functor

I am curious if anyone knows why `g++` compiles the code below but `clang++` gives an error. The code creates a `std::map<int, int, SortCriterion>` with a custom sort functor `SortCriterion`. One can specify via the constructor of `SortCriterion` the type of sorting: ascending or descending. The key comparison is implemented via `operator()(int, int)`. Everything compiles and runs OK under `g++`, even with `-Wall, -Wextra, Wpedantic` etc. However, `clang++` spits an error when invoking the `insert` function, and complains about `const`-ness for the comparison operator, i.e. wants `operator()(int, int) const`.

```
note: candidate function not viable: 'this' argument has type
      'const SortCriterion', but method is not marked const
    bool operator()(int x, int y) //const
```

Now I know that keys in associative containers should not to be messed with, since will damage the internal structure of the container, but is `const`-ness enforced by STL? It seems that the `clang++` expects `std::map<key, value, const comparator>`, whereas `g++` does not impose `const`.

PS: `g++4.9`, `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40)`

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class SortCriterion
{
    bool ascending;
public:
    SortCriterion(bool sorting_type): ascending(sorting_type){};
    // if operator below is not marked const, 
    // clang++ spits a compile-time error on insert
    // however g++ compiles it ok
    bool operator()(int x, int y) //const
    {
        if(ascending) // ascending
            return x<y;
        else
            return x>y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    map<int, string, SortCriterion> m(SortCriterion(false)); // ascending

    m.insert({1,"one element"}); // clang++ compile error here
    m.insert({2,"another element"});
    for(auto elem: m)
        cout << elem.first << ": " << elem.second << endl;
}
```

Comment: @MattMcNabb, thanks! I actually realized just now that my question may be a dupe, http://stackoverflow.com/q/13148513/3093378, and indeed the `operator()` should be marked as `const` in order to be able to use `const` references to `map`s. Then I guess `libstdc++` has a bug.

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved in a deleted answer to the post you link (which I can see due to having 10k rep but you wouldn't be able to). The resolution is to note that Table 102 specifies that when passing `c` as argument to the `map` constructor, then `c` must be of a `CopyConstructible` type, and "Uses a copy of `c` as a comparison object".  So there is actually no specification that the `operator()` function must be `const`.

Comment: @MattMcNabb hmmm, then if `operator()` is not enforced `const`, then it is one's job to ensure `const`-ness for `const` references, otherwise it won't work for `const map&`. So in conclusion `g++` is "right"? Maybe you can post this as an answer so in the future one can find it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I disagree, the deleted answer says because the parameter type of the `map` constructor is `const Compare&` the `operator()` must also be `const`, but that's not correct. The `map` can (and will) make a copy of the comparator object. Kerrek's arguments that the requirements of the various `map` member functions require the `operator()` of the comparator to be `const` is far more convincing. For instance, gcc will choke on the code above if you add the line `auto c = m.count(1);`.

Comment: @Praetorian that was my point. Probably I worded it badly so I'll try again:  the fact that the constructor is defined as taking `const Compare &` does not imply that the comparator must be `const` (however there may be other clauses which imply that the comparator must be const)

Comment: @Praetorian does it choke because it uses `operator()` to test for equivalence?

Comment: @vsoftco Yes, `map::count` is a const member function, so when it tries to call the non-const `operator()` for your comparator, it errors out.

Comment: @vsoftco: "otherwise it won't work for `const map&`" - I'm not sure exactly what you mean there, but it seems wrong ;-).  Even with a `const map`, the `map`'s member functions can create a `Compare()` object that's non-`const`, and indeed there's a `key_compare map::key_comp() const;` function that clearly returns a non-`const` `key_compare` object, which is a `typedef` for the `Compare` template parameter.  So, yes `g++` seems right, but countering that's lots of hints that a `const` version was probably expected: the default `Compare` - `std::less` - defined a `const` version, ...

Comment: ...further, there's a `map::value_compare` in which `operator()` is `const`.  There are places (Table 102) where it says "Uses `Compare()` as a comparison object" - that subtly implies a temporary which means only `const` members can be invoked.  Of course there's also the fact that the `operator` should *logically* be `const`, regardless of whether the Standard mandates it or not.

Comment: @TonyD, I meant that passing `map` by `const` reference won't allow you to call its non-`const` comparator, so it is logical to have it marked `const`

Comment: @vsoftco: but that's not true... whatever member function of the `const map` you call is free to code `Compare c; if c(a, b) ...`.  (There's nothing in the Standard saying the `map`'s `Compare` object isn't stored with `mutable` either, though it's a reasonable assumption.)

Comment: I think the other question is a dupe, however the accepted answer does not seem to resolve it (in light of Tony D's point here)

Comment: @TonyD this becomes trickier than I thought... I don't get why a `const map` can call a non-const functor (the last may have side effect). If I try to do something like you propose, I get `passing const Foo<SortCriterion> as this argument of void Foo<Compare>::do_something() [with Compare = SortCriterion] discards qualifiers [-fpermissive] foo.do_something();`

Comment: @vsoftco that error is talking about calling the non_const function `do_something` on a const object

Comment: @MattMcNabb that's what I meant when I said "passing map by const reference". Don't you then have a `const` object? And if yes, then you should not be able to use `operator()` from the functor if it is not marked `const`. Maybe I am missing something here, sorry for too many comments, but would like to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @vsoftco [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02af94c1bed57f5a)

Comment: @vsoftco: you're right that given a `const object` you can't use a non-`mutable` data member's non-`const` functions, but there key point here was whether the `Compare` object used to do the comparison was necessarily the `map`'s data member and not a non-`const` copy thereof made in the map member function wanting to do a comparison.  Anyway, I think the answer I've posted shows another, conclusive, proof that a non-`const` version is necessary for some of the `map` functionality to work.  Of course with templates you don't necessarily have the compiler test everything that's not called.

Comment: why you can use `{}` to insert element, like `m.insert({1,"one element"});`, but not `std::make_pair(1,"one element")`? I cant compile this with VS2012, is this a new syntax of C++14?

Comment: @MarsonMao `void insert (initializer_list<value_type> il);` is a `C++11` new constructor using initializer lists. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++11 Standard documents a member of `std::map`:

```
class value_compare {
    friend class map;
protected:
    Compare comp;
    value_compare(Compare c) : comp(c) {}
public:
    typedef bool result_type;
    typedef value_type first_argument_type;
    typedef value_type second_argument_type;
    bool operator()(const value_type& x, const value_type& y) const {
        return comp(x.first, y.first);
    }
};
```

...given `value_compare::operator()` is `const`, it can't call a non-`const` member on `comp`.  That means `Compare` absolutely must have a `const` `operator()` for this part of the API to be usable.

Comment: This smells like a defect, it seems odd that a non-const comparator would be OK for all operations except `value_comp` ... which is not used by the map anyway

Comment: `vector` allows different operations depending on the properties of the template type (e.g. non-dfeault-constructible objects can be emplace_back'd, but the vector can't be resized up) so perhaps `map` allows non-const comparator for all operations except`value_comp`. (According to the letter of the standard, that is, it still seems defective)

Comment: @MattMcNabb how do you know `value_compare` is not used in the `map`'s implementation?

Comment: @vsoftco well, it doesn't say that it is